# Play Framework 2.5 - Using "@" when generating html code in controller (html.apply)

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework, twirl

In the controller we are creating a string which shall be interpreted as Html when the page is being rendered. Whenever the string contains scala/twirl code starting with "@" it leads to the page not rendering it correctly/at all.

Controller:

```
// render method
return ok(Html.apply(testButton()), testForm);

public String testButton() throws SQLException {
    result = "<input type='radio' id='@TestForm(\"TestID\").id'   
    name='@TestForm(\"TestID\").name'  value='5'  >" + "Test"; 
    return result;
}
```

Scala.html:

```
@(buttons: Html)(TestForm: Form[TestForm])

@buttons
```

How it should look:

```
<input type='radio' id='TestID' name='TestID'  value=5  >test
```

How it looks:

```
<input type='radio' id='@TestForm("TestID").id' name='@TestForm("TestID").name'  value='5'  >test
```

We also tested this with other examples. The problem really seems to be the `@`. Maybe the parser parses the site once, replaces the `@button` with our code, but doesn't parse that after it. We also tried escaping the `@` with different methods(`@@`, `\@`, no `@`), but it always ended up in plain text afterwards.

What is the easiest method to get an `@` inside another `@` to render?

Comment: Why don't you want to create reusable view for button instead of creating (I would say clumsy) string?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this from within a controller. `@` is parsed by the Twirl compiler at compile-time, but you're trying to introduce it at run-time. It will never work. Even if you *could* get it to work, it wouldn't be a good idea. It breaks the MVC paradigm by muddling the controller code with presentation code.

This should be another Twirl view that looks something like:

```
// I don't know what TestForm is, so this is a guess
// that it exists in the controller and needs to be passed in
@(TestForm: Form) 

<input
  type='radio'
  id='@TestForm("TestID").id'   
  name='@TestForm("TestID").name'  value='5'  
>
```

Comment: thanks for the insight. but how are we supposed to call this view a flexible amount of times with flexible values ?

Comment: What does that mean? A `Form` is a very general object.